# Trying to solve an equation involving the floor function for an algorithm

Tags: calculus, functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have a c++ function which performs the following operation:

```
float calculus(float input, float c1, float c2)
{
    auto output = input;

    while (output >= c1)
        output -= c1;

    return output + c2;
}
```

In my program, I have constant positive float variables called `c1` and `c2` that are being used repetitively as the function argument, and a variable called `counter` which is set at `c1` at startup.

Then, during the execution of the program, I do the following an unknown number of times (integer and positive):

```
counter = calculus(counter, c1, c2);
```

At some unknown point, that variable has a given value that I call $y$, and I would like to know analytically exactly how many times $N$ the function `calculus` has been called.

I think the equation to solve is the following:

$y = c_1 + N \times c_2 - M \times c_1$

with $M$ being the number of times we substracted `c1` to `counter`, and which can be expressed using the floor function:

$M = \lfloor ( c_1 + N \times c_2 ) / c_1 \rfloor$

So the whole equation to solve is:

$y = c_1 + N \times c_2 - \lfloor ( c_1 + N \times c_2 ) / c_1 \rfloor \times c_1$

As it involves the use of the floor function, I have no idea about a way to find the solution.

Can someone please explain how I can solve this equation and / or my problem? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It seems to me that you need some restrictions on the `c1,c2` variables. For instance, if `c2` happens to be a multiple of `c1`, then the sequence of outputs for the `counter` variable becomes `c1,c2,c2,c2,c2,...` and there's no way to know how many iterations have happened.

Comment: You're right, let's say c2 is not a multiple of c1 for the general case. Anyway, if something like this happens, what I would like to know is the minimum value for N that satisfies the equation

Answer (score 1):

Let $\frac{c_1 +Nc_2}{c_1} = x$.Then your equation becomes $$\frac{y}{c_1}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor =\{x\}$$ The RHS is the fractional part of $x$. This implies that the decimal part of $x$ is $\frac{y}{c_1}$, and so for some integer $k $, $$x =k +\frac{y}{c_1} \\ c_1 +Nc_2 =kc_1 +y \\ \implies N= \frac{(k-1)c_1  + y}{c_2}$$

I’ll say that this works only if $0\le y\lt c_1$, though.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer! Yes $y$ is supposed to be lower than $c_1$ anyway, so it can work only in this context. I would like also to ask you how would you find the minimum value for the integer $k$, or maybe some pointers to information about how to solve this in a software program? I looked for Diophantine equations, but it seems that is not what we have here since c1 and c2 are not integer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @IvanC Well, this works for all integers $k$, unless you want $N$ to be an integer as well. I don’t really know what $c_1$ and $c_2$ are, so I guess your best bet is to just try values for $k$ unless $N$ turns out to be a value you want.

Comment: N has to be an integer "as much as possible" (because of rounding errors and stuff like that), so yes for that part I need to figure out how to get a good value for $k$. Thanks for your previous answer anyway it helps ;)

Comment: You’re welcome.